# Snowflake Monitoring and Notification

Tags: notifications, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

¡Hi!
I'm trying to create a monitoring and notification system for resources usage in Snowflake. The idea is to monitor the "Warehouse Load Over Time" and send a notification to an e-mail when the queued queries increase a certain treshold.
Snowflake offer notification for credits consumption, but that's not exactly what I want; however, I could do workaround this characteristic.
I've tried creating a lambda function in aws to query the warehouse_load_history function, but I'm looking for a more cost-efficient solution as the lambda would need to execute every 5-minutes or so.
So, is there any ideas? Has anyone tried this before?

Comment: Please, check the article [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). SO is not a place for opinion-based questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could consider using Snowflake's tasks to query the warehouse_usage_history internal to Snowflake, and if there is a necessary alert to be sent, you can use an `external function` in Snowflake to post an SNS channel, which could then be subscribed to for SMS or Email notifications.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/external-functions.html